# Mysql transactions within transactions

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

In a PHP script working with a mysql database, I recently had the need to use a transaction at a point that happened to be inside another transaction.  All my tests seem to indicate this is working out fine, but I can't find any documentation on this usage.

I want to be sure - are transactions within transactions valid in mysql?  If so, is there a way to find out how many levels deep you are in nested transactions?  (ie. how many rollbacks it would take to return to normal)

Thanks in advance,
Brian

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This page of the manual might interest you : [**12.3.3. Statements That Cause an Implicit Commit**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/implicit-commit.html); quoting a few sentences :

> The statements listed in this section
>   (and any synonyms for them) implicitly
>   end a transaction, as if you had done
>   a `COMMIT` before executing the
>   statement.

And, a bit farther in the page :

> Transaction-control and locking
>   statements.  `BEGIN`, `LOCK TABLES`,
>   `SET autocommit = 1` (if the value is
>   not already 1), `START TRANSACTION`,
>   `UNLOCK TABLES`.

See also this paragraph :

> Transactions cannot be nested. 
> This is
>   a consequence of the implicit `commit`
>   performed for any current transaction
>   when you issue a `START TRANSACTION`
>   statement or one of its synonyms.

Comment: `Transactions cannot be nested` in the same connection, or also in differents?

Comment: General logic says that different connections know nothing about each other. So, transaction in one connection doesn't know about another transaction in different connection. Not tested, but should be true.

Answer (score 74):

Contrary to everyone else's answer, you can effectively create transactions within transactions and it's really easy. You just create SAVEPOINT locations and use ROLLBACK TO *savepoint* to rollback part of the transaction, where *savepoint* is whatever name you give the savepoint.
Link to MySQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/savepoint.html
And of course, none of the queries anywhere in the transaction should be of the type that implicitly commit, or the whole transaction will be committed.

Examples:

```
START TRANSACTION;

# queries that don't implicitly commit

SAVEPOINT savepoint1;

# queries that don't implicitly commit

# now you can either ROLLBACK TO savepoint1, or just ROLLBACK to reverse the entire transaction.

SAVEPOINT savepoint2;

# queries that don't implicitly commit

# now you can ROLLBACK TO savepoint1 OR savepoint2, or ROLLBACK all the way.
# e.g.

ROLLBACK TO savepoint1;
COMMIT; # results in committing only the part of the transaction up to savepoint1
```

In PHP I have written code like this, and it works perfectly:

```
foreach($some_data as $key => $sub_array) {
  $result = mysql_query('START TRANSACTION'); // note mysql_query is deprecated in favor of PDO
  $rollback_all = false; // set to true to undo whole transaction
  for($i=0;$i<sizeof($sub_array);$i++) {
    if($sub_array['set_save'] === true) {
      $savepoint = 'savepoint' . $i;
      $result = mysql_query("SAVEPOINT $savepoint");
    }
    $sql = 'UPDATE `my_table` SET `x` = `y` WHERE `z` < `n`'; // some query/queries
    $result = mysql_query($sql); // run the update query/queries

    $more_sql = 'SELECT `x` FROM `my_table`'; // get data for checking
    $result = mysql_query($more_sql);
    
    $rollback_to_save = false; // set to true to undo to last savepoint
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      // run some checks on the data
      if( /*some check says to go back to savepoint */) {
        $rollback_to_save = true; // or just do the rollback here.
      }
      if( /* some check says to rollback entire transaction */ ) {
        $rollback_all = true;
      }
    }
    if($rollback_all === true) {
      mysql_query('ROLLBACK'); // rollback entire transaction
      break; // break out of for loop, into next foreach
    }
    if($rollback_to_save = true) {
      mysql_query("ROLLBACK TO $savepoint"); // undo just this part of for loop
    }
  } // end of for loop
  mysql_query('COMMIT'); // if you don't do this, the whole transaction will rollback
}
```

Comment: Didn't test it, but I felt the need to comment on how beautiful this is.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu thank you! I don't think I've ever received such a compliment for any of my code. It works perfectly in my application, and it seems a few other people have gotten it to work too, judging by the upvotes.

Comment: That's right, one can set savepoint and rollback to this savepoint inside one transaction. But the point here is that nesting of transactions is not possible because starting inner transaction will implicitly commit previous outer transaction statements and that's probably something that you do not want. This can be problematic: for example if one has class House and another class Room each having its own transaction for DB create statement; here creating Room object inside House object will break outer House's transaction!!!

Comment: @sbrbot "A rose by any other name would smell as sweet." You nest `START TRANSACTION` statements, but the `SAVEPOINT` method I crudely outlined in my answer achieves exactly what a nested transaction would. Suppose you have an array of `room` objects you want to add to a `house` object. You could actually use database constraints to decide when the house is "full". You can try adding each room, and get back a `house full` exception once it's full, which can coincide with the database model spitting back an error and rolling back to "savepointX". "Could not add 5th bathroom. Full House."

Comment: @sbrbot Moreover, since you can make as many SAVEPOINTs as you need, you can nest as deeply as you need. E.g. rooms in a wing of a house, wings in a house, houses in a block. You can roll back to the last room, the last wing, or the last house. Suppose you're adding your 10th house of the block, and you add several rooms but once you add a bathroom you get an error "too much water demand for one block, house canceled." You would `ROLLBACK TO house9complete` and then start the next block. You can have multiple `ROLLBACK` events in a single run through the program. And in fact, that is what I do

Comment: Sometimes I want to create House with all Rooms in it within one single transaction (transaction started inside House class method create). Sometimes I want to create Room only (Room class has its own transaction started in create method). So if I start House transaction and intend to create Rooms in it, Room's start of its (inner) transaction will implicitly commit outer House transaction). Room knows nothing about it is created inside an outer transaction in order to set savepoint.

Comment: @sbrbot There are several ways to solve that. One way is to not have DB queries inside of each class. Whenever any object uses its `save()` method, it would be saved through a `db` object that would have a `transactionLevel` property. That way, any object saved could create a roll back-able savepoint. The `db` object takes care of all the savepoint names and nesting. If no transactions are started, it issues `START TRANSACTION`, otherwise it creates a `SAVEPOINT`. There are other solutions as well. But using the `SAVEPOINT` in any solution will allow for much better DB consistency.

Comment: I do have a db object (using shared DB connection) and used by all my classes (objects). Actually it's an abstract class with db as wrapper for all my classes. I got the idea from your comment with _transactionalLevel_ property - should db start a transaction or not (yes by default). When I create Room inside a House, I should set this property and tell DB not to start transaction since it has been started in outer class.

Comment: The problem with savepoints is that you have to manage them at client side (i.e. track if transaction is active, track savepoint names, etc.). This is different from nested transactions, which are managed from server side.

Comment: @AnrDaemon You mean client code outside of MySQL? I implemented it in PHP, but it seems like you could also implement it in a stored procedure. No need to track global savepoint names. "A new savepoint level is created when a stored function is invoked or a trigger is activated. The savepoints on previous levels become unavailable and thus do not conflict with savepoints on the new level. When the function or trigger terminates, any savepoints it created are released and the previous savepoint level is restored."  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/savepoint.html

Answer (score 14):

> I want to be sure - are transactions
>   within transactions valid in mysql?

No.

Answer (score 11):

MySql doesn't support nested transactions. There are a few ways that you can emulate it though. First, you can use savepoints as a form of transaction, so that gives you two levels of transactions; I've used this for testing, but I'm not sure about the limitations, if you use it in production code. A simpler solution is to ignore the second `begin transaction` and instead increase a counter. For each `commit`, you decrease it. Once you hit zero, you do an actual `commit`. There are obvious limitations of this; Eg. a rollback will roll *all* transactions back, but for a case where you only use transactions for error-handling, that may be acceptable.

Answer (score 7):

There are some great answers in this thread, however, if you use innoDB as your MySQL storage engine and are using MySQL 5.0.3 or higher, you get nested transactions right out of the box without the need for any extra work on your part or any of the fancy techniques described by others in this thread.

***From the MySQL docs on XA Transactions:***

> MySQL 5.0.3 and up provides server-side support for XA transactions. Currently, this support is available for the InnoDB storage engine. The MySQL XA implementation is based on the X/Open CAE document Distributed Transaction Processing: The XA Specification. This document is published by The Open Group and available at http://www.opengroup.org/public/pubs/catalog/c193.htm. Limitations of the current XA implementation are described in Section E.5, “Restrictions on XA Transactions”.

***My XA Transaction Example Just For You:***

```
# Start a new XA transaction
XA START;

    # update my bank account balance, they will never know!
    UPDATE `bank_accounts` SET `balance` = 100000 WHERE `id` = 'mine';

    # $100,000.00 is a bit low, I'm going to consider adding more, but I'm not sure so 
    # I will start a NESTED transaction and debate it...
    XA START;

        # max int money! woo hoo!
        UPDATE `bank_accounts` SET `balance` = 2147483647 WHERE `id` = 'mine';

    # maybe thats too conspicuous, better roll back
    XA ROLLBACK;


# The $100,000 UPDATE still applies here, but the max int money does not, going for it!
XA COMMIT;

# Oh No!  Sirens!  It's the popo's!!! run!!
# What the hell are they using ints for money columns anyway!  Ahhhh!
```

MySQL Documentation For XA Transactions:

- [13.3.7. XA
  Transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/xa.html)
- [13.3.7.1. XA Transaction SQL
  Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/xa-statements.html)
- [13.3.7.2. XA Transaction States](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/xa-states.html)
- [E.6. Restrictions on XA Transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/xa-restrictions.html)

***I <3 XA Transactions 4 Eva!***

Comment: Tried on MySQL 5.6. The "XA" commands require a string xid, and trying to start a nested one gives this: "ERROR 1399 (XAE07): XAER_RMFAIL: The command cannot be executed when global transaction is in the  ACTIVE state"

Comment: I just ran into the same issue as @HectorJ. I wish this worked, but it does not.

Comment: @RyanEwen Anything wrong with my  `SAVEPOINT` solution? Works perfectly for me.

Comment: @ButtleButkus Yes unfortunately for me it wasn't a proper solution. I can't quite remember why. I think it had to do with nested functions and/or queries that implicitly committed. I ended up realizing that I shouldn't use transactions in my applications functions as they can get nested, and rather only use transactions at the highest level of code where I can wrap the entire process in a transaction without any conflict

Comment: @RyanEwen it would work if your application keeps track of transaction nesting level to determine whether to issue a ‘START TRANSACTION’ or a ‘SAVEPOINT savepoint-n’. Of course, you can’t use DDL statements like add columns, tables, etc during a transaction. You can sometimes use temporary tables, though. In my case, I create a temporary table before starting the transaction. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html

Comment: I also wish this worked, but sadly not -- as other users pointed out, XA START is not valid syntax in MySQL, and nesting does not work either.


SAVEPOINT only works for ROLLBACK, not for COMMIT.  I'd like to COMMIT everything after a SAVEPOINT, without affecting the original transaction.  Today I use a second connection instead, but that can't access the temp tables I want on the main connection.  I could use persistent tables instead, but then they won't clean up automatically.  The ideal solution would be a nested transaction on the connection that already has the temp tabled data.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check your testing methadology.  Outside of [MaxDB](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/maxdb-transactions.html), MySQL doesn't support anything remotely like nested transactions.

Comment: "MySQL doesn't support anything remotely like nested transactions." Wouldn't you say that savepoints are anything like nested transactions?

Answer (score -1):

It does:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/xa.html

Comment: are these really nested transactions? got some samples?