# Recursive/nested transaction

Tags: mysql, sqltransaction

I have 2 store procedures A, B, both are in a transaction block. The problems is A calls B, so, there is recursive/nested transaction. I'm not sure is there problem? What will happen when I call A?

Cited from "MySQL Stored Procedure Programming":

> `START TRANSACTION` signifies the commencement of a new transaction. If an existing transaction is already in progress, then `START TRANSACTION` will issue an implicit `COMMIT`. When you issue `START TRANSACTION`, the autocommit property (described in the next section) is effectively and implicitly set to 0 until the transaction ends. We recommend that you explicitly commit or roll back existing transactions before any `START TRANSACTION` statements, since the implicit `COMMIT` might not be obvious to someone reading or maintaining your code.

Answer (score 2):

If both procedures set/use locks on the same resource, then you'll get a deadlock. `B` holds a lock on some table/row/field that `A` also requires, meaning `A` can't get its own lock. So `A` will sit and wait to acquire the lock until the DBMS times it out and rolls things back.

Comment: They don't use the same tables, just nested transaction on different tables. Is there problem?

Comment: Possibly if any of those tables have foreign keys against each other. But if they're fully independent, then no, should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

As long as B doesn't also call A, you don't have a recursive situation, just a nested transaction - which should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. They just cannot overlap. You can do it using SAVEPOINT.

See this answer:

[Mysql transactions within transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490846/mysql-transactions-within-transactions/11941449#11941449)

Comment: I answered that you can do it with a savepoint. I have seen many answers consisting mainly of a link with a short explanation.

Comment: If I delete this answer do I get my points back?

Comment: Yes, the reputation changes of any votes on a post are reversed when the post is deleted (except when the votes have been cast long ago). But the downvote has been reversed.