# MySQL nested transactions - not rolling back

Tags: mysql, transactions, rollback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are nested transactions allowed in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306869/are-nested-transactions-allowed-in-mysql)

I have s stored procedure that uses transactions and inside a transaction calls another procedure that also uses transactions and updates a table. The second procedure is called inside a loop and every call updates a single row. This second procedure also creates a temporary table. 
Engine is InnoDB for permanent tables and MyISAM for temporary tables.
MySQL version is 5.5.16.

What I want is to rollback  all the updates made by the second  procedure if an error happens.

Is this possible ?  I know that an DDL statement and start transaction; will issue a commit but is there a way around it?

The code looks something like this:
(rollback obviously doesn't work)

```
delimiter $$
drop procedure if exists `proc1`$$
create procedure `proc1`( 
  ...#some variables
) 
modifies sql data

begin
    declare error int default 0;
    declare continue handler for sqlexception
    begin 
        set error=1;
    end;


     drop temporary table if exists table1;
     create temporary table table1 (

         id int unsigned, 
         col1 decimal(12,6) default 0, 
         col2 decimal (12,6) default 0, 
         col3 decimal (12,6),

         primary key (id)) engine=MyISAM;

     START TRANSACTION;
        begin
           declare id_1 int unsigned;
           declare v1 decimal(12,6) default 0;
           declare v2 decimal(12,6) default 0;
           declare v3 decimal(12,6) default 0;

           declare done int default 0;

          declare cur cursor for select id, col1, col2 from table1;
          declare continue handler for not found set done=1;

          begin
              open cur; 
              wh: while done=0 do
                  fetch cur into id, v1, v2;
                   if done=1 then
                          leave wh;
                   end if;

                   set v3=v1+v2 ;                                      
                   update table1 set col3=v3 where id =id_1;

                   CALL  proc2(id_1, v1, v2, v3);

                   end while wh;
                   close cur;
                   set done=0;
                 end;

            end;
           if error=0 then
                  commit;
                  set status=1;

            else 
                  rollback;
                 set status=-1;
            end if;


end$$
```

Answer (score 6):

You can only have one transaction open at a time. Attempting to start a new transaction when there is already an existing transaction results in the existing transaction being committed. However, you can emulate nested transactions using [savepoints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/savepoint.html).