# How to use nested transaction in Delphi dbExpress component with MySQL

Tags: mysql, delphi, transactions, dbexpress

I'm trying to do a nested transaction using dbExpress in Delphi XE3 that is connected to MySQL 5.6.13.

Here is my example code to do a Nested transaction:

```
...

  dbxTransaction := _connection.BeginTransaction(TDBXIsolations.ReadCommitted);


  // just to check if nested is suported
  supportsNestedBol := dbxTransaction.Connection.DatabaseMetaData.SupportsNestedTransactions;


  try
    _sqlQuery.Close;
    _sqlQuery.SQL.Clear;
    _sqlQuery.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO test(cod, name) VALUES(:cod, :name)');
    _sqlQuery.ParamByName('cod').AsInteger := Test.Cod;
    _sqlQuery.ParamByName('name').AsAnsiString := Test.Name;
    _sqlQuery.ExecSQL(False);


    //calls a nested function that has another transaction
    Employee.Save();


    _connection.CommitFreeAndNil(dbxTransaction);
    Result := True;
  except
    on Exc:Exception do
    begin
      _connection.RollBackFreeAndNil(dbxTransaction);
      raise Exc;
      Result := False;
    end;
  end;

...

function Employee.Save():Boolean;
begin
...
  dbxTransaction02 := _connection.BeginTransaction(TDBXIsolations.ReadCommitted);

  try
    _sqlQuery.Close;
    _sqlQuery.SQL.Clear;
    _sqlQuery.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO employee(cod, name) VALUES(:cod, :name)');
    _sqlQuery.ParamByName('cod').AsInteger := Employee.Cod;
    _sqlQuery.ParamByName('name').AsAnsiString := Employee.Name;
    _sqlQuery.ExecSQL(False);
    _connection.CommitFreeAndNil(dbxTransaction02);
    Result := True;
  except
    on Exc:Exception do
    begin
      _connection.RollBackFreeAndNil(dbxTransaction02);
      raise Exc;
      Result := False;
    end;
  end;
end;
...
```

If I put a break point and check the variable `supportsNestedBol` the value is `False`. 
So, I'm not sure if is the connector "libmysql.dll" that I'm using that not support nested transaction or if is the way that I'm trying to do it.

Some help?

Comment: [Or MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306869/are-nested-transactions-allowed-in-mysql)...

Comment: Nice know. But I was following the question that you pointed me and in the answers I understand that the connector could have suport to nested transactions. So I would like to know if is possible some dbExpress connector of Delphi to do nested transacition working on MySSQL.