# how mysql handle multiple START TRANSACTION (nesting?)

Tags: mysql, transactions, nested

I can't find the answer : how MySQL handle when in the same connection I call multiple time START TRANSACTION

for example does the autocommit the current one in order to start a fresh new or does he nest them?

NB : this is not a duplicate of [Are nested transactions allowed in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306869/are-nested-transactions-allowed-in-mysql) because I don't whant to know if mysql allow it, or how to simulate this behaviou. I found that mysql does not nest the  transactions and I want to know how MySQL actually handle nested START TRANSACTION (by commiting the old one, by ignoring the new start transaction, ...)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306869/are-nested-transactions-allowed-in-mysql

Comment: I found this ressource, a similar subject is approached, but it don't speak about the actual nesting of START TRANSACTION wich can occur in source code. I found an article on wikipedia saying that mysql do not support the nesting, but in this coase how does he behave? I found nowhere an answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Read the manual instead of wikipedia.

First entry from googling "mysql start transaction":

[13.3.1 START TRANSACTION, COMMIT, and ROLLBACK Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)

> Beginning a transaction causes any pending transaction to be committed. See Section 13.3.3, “[Statements That Cause an Implicit Commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/implicit-commit.html)”, for more information.