# (transaction)Is this a recoverable schedule?

Tags: mysql, serialization, transactions

Recoverable schedule is:
A schedule where, for each pair of transactions Ti and Tj, if Tj reads a data item previously written by Ti, then the commit operation of Ti precedes the commit operation of Tj.

```
T1        T2      T3
w(x) 
                 w(x)
         r(x)   commit
        commit
commit
```

In this case, T2 commits before T1, so is it non-recoverable?

I understand T3 have to commit before T2 to make it recoverable.

However, T3 has override T1's written value, 
does T1 have to commit before T2 to achieve a recoverable schedule?

Please help me! Thank you so much!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306869/are-nested-transactions-allowed-in-mysql for more info. Use save points if you need to rollback to a certain point.

Comment: @Sloan thanks you for your answer. But my question is, whether the example is a recoverable schedule?

Comment: See this about recoverable schedules: https://sites.google.com/site/projectcodebank/computer-engineering-notes/recoverable-and-cascadeless

Comment: @SloanThrasher Because T3 has override x that written by T1, I don't understand does T1 also have to commit before T2, to make it recoverable.